# Gradle mavenDeployer getting 501

Tags: gradle

I've been working to get our Gradle build working again after Maven Central converted to https but I'm stuck on an issue with our upload to Nexus task.

The gradle script looks like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "$nexus_url"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

task uploadtoNexus (type: Upload) {
    ...

    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "$repoUrl") {
                authentication(userName: "***", password: "***")
                releases(updatePolicy: 'never')
                snapshots(updatePolicy: 'always')
            }

            pom.groupId = "$groupId"
            pom.project{ packaging 'war'
                version "$verNo" }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when running the uploadtoNexus task:

```
:uploadtoNexus
Downloading: com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.6/jackson-bom-2.8.6.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.6/jackson-bom-2.8.6.pom
:uploadtoNexus FAILED
```

I've tried adding https repositories to my global maven settings.xml, but it doesn't seem to be picking up those changes.  I know my settings.xml is loading because I did manage to override the value to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, but I can't get the build to use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 instead of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 for the jackson-bom.

global settings.xml

```
<repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central1</id>
                    <name>central maven repo https</name>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                 </repository>
                 <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>central maven repo https</name>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                 </repository>
                 <repository>
                    <id>maven</id>
                    <name>maven </name>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                 </repository>
        </repositories>
```

Here is the debug info when I try to run the job:

```
12:30:35.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Maven Ant Tasks version: 2.1.3
12:30:35.856 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\ckantzer\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_empty_settings5984918988776117085.xml
12:30:35.956 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: C:\Users\ckantzer\.m2\settings.xml
12:30:36.196 [DEBUG] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@167a21b7 pairs: {GET /maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.6/jackson-bom-2.8.6.pom HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept-Encoding: gzip}{Pragma: no-cache}{User-Agent: maven-artifact/3.0.4 (Java 1.8.0_20; Windows 8.1 6.3)}{Host: repo1.maven.org}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
12:30:36.329 [DEBUG] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7c0df4ab12 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 501 HTTPS Required}{Server: Varnish}{Content-Type: text/plain}{Content-Length: 133}{Accept-Ranges: bytes}{Date: Thu, 12 Mar 2020 16:30:36 GMT}{Via: 1.1 varnish}{Connection: close}{X-Served-By: cache-chi21159-CHI}{X-Cache: MISS}{X-Cache-Hits: 0}{X-Timer: S1584030636.304049,VS0,VE0}
12:30:36.332 [INFO] [system.out] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.8.6' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.6/jackson-bom-2.8.6.pom
12:30:36.334 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
```

We are running an older version of Gradle (2.3) and would prefer to get this working with the current version than update to a newer version and have to refactor our build script.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT - I am using springboot 1.5.1 which is where the jackson dependency is coming from.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Which Gradle version is this and what's defined in your [repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) closure?

Comment: Gradle 2.3.  I've edited my post to include the repositories.

Comment: Using springboot 1.5.1 which is where the jackson dependency is coming from.